# UI design - popup

Tags: css, user-interface

I am currently developing a website.

Let me narrate the issue that i facing:

When users opens website they will get two options in a small pop-up.

1. Fisrt option in the popup will direct to sub-domain 1
2. second option in the popup will direct to sub-domain 2

now my query is, how to present this in a most appealing User Interface... Can you please give some ideas on this.

It would be really helpful if anyone can give the website names who have already implemented similar one / any UI related websites.

Thanks a lot

Regards,
Gourav

Comment: You will have better luck here - http://ui.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question leaves too much to the imagination. Define your goal, and I think you'll answer your own question...

1. Are you selling products skewed
   toward different buyers (sub#1=cars,
   sub#2=trucks)?
2. Are you selling the
   same product to different
   demographics (boys click here, girls
   click there)?
3. Is it the same product built for different markets (commercial products, residential products)?
4. Whatever your situation is...

**Determine the goal**, and the rest should fall into place.

To the UI...

1. Since you're going to halt the visitor as soon as they land, just split your home page down the middle with whatever graphic you see fit (big button on either side...cars | trucks....girls | boys...commercial | residential) -- This approach doesn't require any JS, popups, etc. very clean and to the point.
2. If you want to have "canned" content on the home page, but force them to make a choice, I would prefer an element that slides into the screen like the "Welcome Back" message on SO, or even a screen take over (tho not as much because they're intrusive as !@#$).
3. Pop-ups are so 1998 :-) Avoid at all cost

Here's a couple links on UI design/technique that may help (tons of technique and examples):
[10 Techniques](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/12/15/10-useful-techniques-to-improve-your-user-interface-designs/), and [40 Helpful Resources on UI Design Patterns](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/)

Answer (score 2):

I think that instead of pop ups you should show those two websites and their previews (clickable) on the page side by side, and whatever preview user clicks, he may be redirected to that page.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... is any website already used this feature... so that i can have a better idea

Comment: I don't know of any website like this. Just came to my mind and thought that it might be good to show preview to the user so that he may select. P.S. Please mark my answer as answer if you think it is the right answer...